# Why is my Clojure project slow on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: audio, clojure, raspberry-pi

I've been writing a simple Clojure framework for playing music (and later some other stuff) for my Raspberry Pi. The program parses a given music directory for songs and then starts listening for control commands (such as start, stop, next song) via a TCP interface.

The code is available via GitHub:
https://github.com/jvnn/raspi-framework

The current version works just fine on my laptop, it starts playing music (using the JLayer library) when instructed to, changes songs, and stops just as it should. The uberjar takes a few seconds to start on the laptop as well, but when I try to run it on the Raspberry Pi, things get insanely slow.

Just starting up the program so that all classes are loaded and the actual program code starts executing takes way over a minute. I tried to run it with the -verbose:class switch, and it seems the jvm spends the whole time just loading tons of classes (for Clojure and everything else).

When the program finally starts, it does react to the commands given, but the playback is very laggy. There is a short sub-second sound, then a pause for almost a second, then another sound, another pause etc... So the program is trying to play something but it just can't do it fast enough. CPU usage is somewhere close to 98%.

Now, having an Android phone and all, I'm sure Java can be executed on such hardware well enough to play some mp3 files without any troubles. And I know that JLayer (or parts of it) is used in the gdx game development framework (that also runs on Android) so it shouldn't be a problem either.

So everything points in me being the problem. Is there something I can do either with leiningen (aot is already enabled for all files), the Raspberry Pi, or my code that could make things faster?

Thanks for your time!

**UPDATE:**
I made a tiny test case to rule out some possibilities and the problems still exist with the following Clojure code:

```
(ns test.core
  (:import [javazoom.jl.player.advanced AdvancedPlayer])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  []
  (let [filename "/path/to/a/music/file.mp3"
        fis (java.io.FileInputStream. filename)
        bis (java.io.BufferedInputStream. fis)
        player (AdvancedPlayer. bis)]
    (doto player (.play) (.close))))
```

The project.clj:

```
(defproject test "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [javazoom/jlayer "1.0.1"]]
  :javac-options ["-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "-Xlint:-options"]
  :aot :all
  :main test.core)
```

So, no core.async and no threading. The playback *did* get a bit smoother, but it's still about 200ms music and 200ms pause.

Comment: I think this could be related to the smaller cache size on the pi's CPU. Clojure is great, but idiomatic Clojure is much more demanding in terms of cache churn than most other languages (in particular because of its heavy usage of immutible data structures).

Comment: I think this wouldn't explain the playback problems (and not really the slow startup time either I guess). Because (at least if the code works like I've meant it to work) during the playback, which is handled by a java library, all Clojure code should be parked and waiting for some async channel input.

Comment: That parking probably involves some context switching. Context switching smashes your cache, which is expensive (especially with a slow bus). Once you have a media stream that is going directly from RAM (or even disk) to an output device without modification, the thing that makes it skip is context switching, and the more cache that the context switch needs, the more extreme the skipping issues will be.

Comment: I updated the question with a minimal test case. The code I added is now the only thing that is going on, but it's still far from smooth. I also checked that sound is working on the Pi otherwise by playing the music file with gstreamer and it worked without issues.

Comment: If that code skips, then the problem is either the javazoom classes, or the JVM. I was in the midst of writing an answer, but I looked through the javazoom docs and found no options for a buffer size on output device. If it doesn't let you tweak the buffer size you should simply be using a different library (given how stripped down that code is, I can't see what other than changing output buffer size would improve the performance).

Comment: Did this ultimately iron out for you? would you say clojure reasonably works fine on the Pi?

Comment: I gave up on Clojure on the Pi at that point and rewrote my program with Python. Haven't had time to try it out again, so sorry, but I have no clue about the current state of things.

Answer (score 5):

Most obvious to me is that you have a lot of un-hinted interop code, leading to very expensive runtime reflection. Try running `lein check` (I think that's built in, but maybe you need a plugin) and fixing the reflection issues it points out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. lein check didn't tell me anything though, the only output was "Compiling namespace...". But I guess reflection can't be a reason for the long start-up time even if it makes the program slower on runtime?

Comment: re startup time...Clojure is just big, and a raspberry pi is small. If you are seeing a bunch of time spend loading classes at startup, that is probably because there are a lot of classes to load. I imagine your jar file is pretty hefty, compared to what a pi wants to see.

Comment: Alright, this is what I was afraid to hear. I was hoping there would be something (optimisations, different java versions etc.) that could be done to make things better.